# Understanding a piece of code in C++

Tags: visual-c++

Can you help me understand the following code?

```
void errorexit(char *pchar) {
  // display an error to the standard err.

  fprintf(stderr, pchar);
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What bit don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `errorexit("Error Message")` will print "Error Message" to the standard error stream (often in a terminal) and exit the program.  Any programs (such as the shell) that called your program will know that the there was an error since your program exited with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing out the string pointed to by pchar to the standard error output via fprintf and then forcing the application to exit with a return code of 1.  This would be used for critical errors when the application can't continue running.

Answer (score 0):

That function prints the provided string and a newline to stderr and then terminates the current running program, providing 1 as the return value.

`fprintf` is like `printf` in that it outputs characters, but `fprintf` is a little different in that it takes a file handle as an argument. I this case `stderr` is the file handle for standard error. This handle is already defined for you by stdio.h, and corresponds to the error output stream. `stdout` is what `printf` outputs to, so `fprintf(stdout, "hello")` is equivalent to `printf("hello")`.

`exit` is a function that terminates the execution of the current process and returns whatever value was its argument as the return code to the parent process (usually the shell). A non-zero return code usually indicates failure, the specific value indicating the type of failure.

If you ran this program from the shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "errorexit.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    errorexit("Goodbye :(");
    printf("Just kidding!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You'd see this output:

```
Hello world!
Goodbye :(
```

And your shell would show "1" as the return value (in bash, you can view the last return code with `echo $?`).

Note that "Just kidding!" would *not* be printed, as `errorexit` calls `exit`, ending the program before `main` finishes.